# How player(sprite) in the phaser will opposite or reverse while going left and right?

Tags: sprites, phaser

I am developing a game where my player has to look to see forward when I am pressing right arrow key. But how can I make it look reverse after pressing left arrow? I can create a sprite of reverse look but how can load that while pressing left and at the same time forward player should be destroyed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I set the sprite's scale.x to `-1` to flip it horizontally. You can see an example here: https://phaser.io/examples/v2/sprites/scale-a-sprite some of those sprites are scaled to negative values, and they appear mirrored.

[image: sprite scale]

Another approach is to flip the sprites in your assets. This has the added advantage of looking correct if the character is handed - if they were holding a gun, they won't be switching their gun hand depending on which direction they're facing. [Phaser's platformer example](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/arcade-physics/platformer-basics) does this, and has separate left and right animation frames:

[image: phaser dude]

Comment: I ran into some weird issues with setting X to -1.  I just mirrored my image to create "left-walk" animation.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When your character is looking rightward, his width is positive. So, all you need to do is to invert proportionally his width.

Visual example:

**This image's width is 779px**

[image]

**And this image's width is -779px**

[image]

When reversing, also remember to add the X-axis by the width, so that the character's sprite doesn't "walk" behind the total units that the width of the sprite has